# Data preprocessing - Time Series data resets its values - Detection & Correction

Tags: python, preprocessing, anomaly-detection, outlier

**1. Summarize the problem**

I currently trying to work with time series data from sensors which has some problems regarding resetting it values. For example some cumulative values gets reset and don't add up the latest value.

```
| timestamp | col_01 | col_02 | col_03 |
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
| 123456    | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 123457    | 12,8   | 0,14   | 0      |
| 123458    | 85,7   | 3,87   | 1,5    |
| 123459    | 140,6  | 41,2   | 1,5    |
| 123460    | 210,8  | 78,1   | 5,7    |
| 123461    | 14,9   | 9,42   | 0,8    | <- reset
| 123462    | 60,2   | 12,47  | 1,9    |
```

**2. Provide details and any research**

The dataset consists of multiple GB of sensor data and checking every row for a reset and summing it up isn't a very efficient method and consumes a lot of time.

**3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

I tried using some outlier detection with the Z- & IQR-Score Method, but these approaches detect the wrong values. Mostly the points after the sensor data rested itself.

What's a suitable approach to solve this problem? Using a time series cycle detection to get the timestamps of the resets?
The next step after detecting these outliers would be to correct or remove them from the dataset.

Comment: How do you define a reset, do the values always reset to zero? Are the values after a reset always lower then the values before the reset?

Comment: Yes, the values are always lower then the values before and they don't always reset to zero.

Comment: Would a simple comparison between the current value and the previous value work? If the current value if lower than the previous value then the row is a reset, otherwise it is a continuation of the timeseries.

Comment: Not really. comparing 40 mil+ lines with each other on a high dimensionality basis isn't a very compute effective solution.

Comment: If it is just about the number of lines you could relatively easily process the data in chunks of let's say 1 million in `pandas`, comparing for a single column if the current value is lower than the previous value using the `.shift()` method. Since `pandas` is built on top of `numpy` these operations are vectorized and really quick to compute.

Comment: yeah, but i am using pandas mainly for small visualizations. It' doesnt really scale very well and can not be distributed among clusters.

Comment: each chunk can be processed independently, so it can be distributed among many workers in a cluster

Comment: i tried a few anomaly detection models, but nothing resulted in accaptable detections. My current solution is to compute the delta between the row t and t+1. If it's negative there's a reset and i can remove the timestamp via simple filter.